# Vertical space between chapter number and chapter title using sectsty

Tags: spacing, sectsty

I am using sectsty to format my chapter titles, but I want the vertical space between Chapter # and Chapter Title gone, and I can't find a way to do it without losing the styles applied by sectsty.

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt, paper=a4]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\chapternumberfont{\LARGE\uppercase}
\chapterfont{\thispagestyle{empty}\LARGE\centering\uppercase}
\sectionfont{\large\uppercase}
\subsectionfont{\normalsize}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Cap name one}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Section 1.1}
\lipsum[2-4]

\chapter{Cap name two}
\lipsum[5]
\section{Section 2.1}
\lipsum[6]

\end{document}
```

Now if I add this following piece of code before `\begin{document}` the space is gone, but so is the style from secsty

```
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space {\thechapter}
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 0\p@
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    {\parbox{\textwidth}{\Huge \bfseries \linespread{1.2}\selectfont #1\par\nobreak}}
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `titlesec` instead `sectsty`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\makeatletter
\titleformat
  {\chapter}
  [display]
  {\centering\LARGE}
  {\MakeUppercase{\@chapapp\enskip\thechapter}}
  {0pt}
  {\MakeUppercase}
\makeatother
\titleformat*{\section}{\large\MakeUppercase}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalsize}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{empty}}{}{}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Cap name one}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Section 1.1}
\lipsum[2-4]

\chapter{Cap name two}
\lipsum[5]
\section{Section 2.1}
\lipsum[6]

\end{document}
```

Note that I have changed `fontsize=12pt` and `paper=a4` because they are unknown by class `book`.

Result:

[image]